# subsetting a dataset in R

Tags: r, split, subset, sapply

I have a question filtering a dataset based on sum of counts

My file looks like this:

```
g1  a   2
g1  a   3
g1  a   0
g1  b   1
g2  b   3
g2  c   4
g2  d   9
g3  e   1
g3  f   3
g4  g   10
g4  h   18
g4  i   23
```

First column is gene names. I want to calculate from the third column, the sum associated with each gene, for g1 it's 6 for g2 it's 16 and so on. Then the condition is if the sum of each gene is > 10 then filter the above input dataset such that my output looks like

```
g2  b   3
g2  c   4
g2  d   9
g4  g   10
g4  h   18
g4  i   23
```

this is what I have tried so far:

```
tab <- read.data("input.txt",header=FALSE)
genelist <- split(tab,tab[,1])
```

How can i sum it and filter it out > 10. I think I have to use sapply to loop it through but i am stuck here.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: @NelsonGon Not exactly.  The OP wants to retain the original rows, not just the summed value :-)

Comment: Maybe use `dplyr` `mutate`? My bad!

Comment: with `dplyr` you can do`df %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  filter(sum(V3) > 10)
`

Comment: @RonakShah I can't actually find a duplicate, so maybe post that as an answer.

Comment: If you want to keep the `Sum` column: `df %>% group_by(V1) %>% 
  mutate(Sum=sum(V3)) %>% 
  filter(Sum > 10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
n_vars <- 40
gene <- sample(x=c("g1","g2","g3","g4"),size=n_vars,replace = TRUE)
v1 <- sample(x=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g"),size=n_vars,replace = TRUE)
result <- rnorm(n=n_vars,mean=0,sd=10)

df <- data.frame(gene,v1,result) %>% 
  arrange(gene,v1) %>% 
  group_by(gene,v1) %>% 
  summarise(total=sum(result)) %>% 
  filter(total>10)
```

Comment: this works fine, can you explain the code, new to dplyr

Comment: sure, which part don't you understand? Take a look at https://www.tidyverse.org/